# Enforcing a common template type parameter among two template type parameters that are themselves templates

Tags: c++, templates, type-parameter, template-templates

In C++, is there any way to ensure that two or more template type parameters are themselves template types with a common template type parameter?

Let's say that I have this:

```
struct ArbitraryType {};

template <typename T>
class ArbitraryTemplateClass1 {
  /* ... */
};

template <typename T>
class ArbitraryTemplateClass2 {
  /* ... */
};
```

And I want a template that can take `ArbitraryTemplateClass1` and `ArbitraryTemplateClass2` as template type parameters, but ensure they both have a common template type parameter `T` (and then do something with the type `T`). For example, I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
template <typename U <typename T>, typename V<T>> // desired (but incorrect) syntax
struct CommonTemplateTypeParameterProducer {
  T Produce() { return T(); }
};

// Which would allow this:
int main() {
  CommonTemplateTypeParameterProducer<ArbitraryTemplateClass1<ArbitraryType>, 
                                      ArbitraryTemplateClass2<ArbitraryType>> producer;

  // Type of t should be ArbitraryType
  auto t = producer.Produce();

  // This should fail to instantiate CommonTemplateTypeParameterProducer because U and V don't share a common T
  //CommonTemplateTypeParameterProducer<ArbitraryTemplateClass1<ArbitraryType>, 
  //                                    ArbitraryTemplateClass2<int>>         producer2; 

}
```

Are there any mechanisms that allow this kind of behavior without having direct knowledge of the arbitrary template classes and the arbitrary type? (something like adding a typedef to `ArbitraryTemplateClass1` that specifies the type of `T` would not be an option). If possible, I would also like to avoid adding a third template type parameter to `CommonTemplateTypeParameterProducer;` ideally I would like the template to be able to deduce the common type that it is enforcing.

Note: Something like this would also help with being able to ensure that two template type parameters that are also variadic templates both have identical template arguments.

I have looked into C++ concepts/constraints/requirements and template template parameters, but so far none seem to offer solutions to this particular problem.

Comment: `ArbitraryTemplateClass1<ArbitraryType>` is not a template, but a type.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Understood, I'm unsure how to phrase it clearly. How would you describe a type that is also an instantiation of a template with another type as its template argument?

Comment: its not about phrasing your question. just pointing out the mistake in your code. Your template would instantiated via `CommonTemplateTypeParameterProducer<ArbitraryTemplateClass1, 
                                      ArbitraryTemplateClass2<ArbitraryType>>` ie first argument is a template not a type (neglicting the issue in the second argument)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai It's not a mistake that my code has ArbitraryTemplateClass1<ArbitraryType> instead of ArbitraryTemplateClass1 alone. If it was the latter, my question about enforcing a common template type parameter wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: yeah, sorry I totally misread the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but might not be the best design, because if somebody will need to add *another* template parameter to `ArbitraryTemplateClass1`, everything will break. Or if you decide to make a version of it that's not templated, and only works for one specific type.

It's better to add something like `using type = T;` to `ArbitraryTemplateClass1`/`2`, and check that in your template instead of the actual template parameter. `CommonTemplateTypeParameterProducer` should have no business policing the template arguments of its template arguments.

```
#include <concepts>

template <typename T>
struct A
{
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
struct B
{
    using type = T;
};

template <typename X, typename Y>
requires std::same_as<typename X::type, typename Y::type>
struct Foo
{
    X x;
    Y y;
};

int main()
{
    Foo<A<int>, B<int>> foo;
}
```

---

Here's another option. It has the same issue as your proposed design, but at least you don't need to spell the template argument twice:

```
template <typename T>
struct A {};

template <typename T>
struct B {};

template <
    template <typename> typename X,
    template <typename> typename Y,
    typename T
>
struct Foo
{
    X<T> x;
    Y<T> y;
};

int main()
{
    Foo<A, B, int> foo;
}
```

---

And lastly, here's exactly what you asked for. I added a helper template to extract the template argument from arbitrary templates. This, again, has the issue I described above, and also requires spelling the template argument twice.

```
#include <concepts>

template <typename T>
struct GetTemplateArgument {};
template <template <typename> typename T, typename U>
struct GetTemplateArgument<T<U>> {using type = U;};

template <typename T>
struct A {};

template <typename T>
struct B {};

template <typename X, typename Y>
requires std::same_as<typename GetTemplateArgument<X>::type, typename GetTemplateArgument<Y>::type>
struct Foo
{
    X x;
    Y y;
};

int main()
{
    Foo<A<int>, B<int>> foo;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the last one is just the kind of thing I was looking for! The main reason I was looking for something other than your first solution is because I want to write Foo in a way that works even if I don't have direct access to modifying A or B. I also didn't want something like the second because I may or may not already know the common type of A and B, like in the case that Foo is within another template and all I have are two types that should only work if they have common template params.

Comment: @js87 Hmm, I see. Then yes, perhaps it's justified. It depends on how customizable you want it to be, and whether you expect users to write more of the classes like `ArbitraryTemplateClass1` in the future. If this was my code, I'd probably look at the implementation of `ArbitraryTemplateClass1`, perhaps there's a way to infer the template argument even if they didn't add a typedef.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a partial specialization that matches the requirement.

Use a primary class that takes 2 type parameters. Don't define it, so you'll get an error if you try to use it:

```
template <typename, typename>
struct CommonTemplateTypeParameterProducer;
```

Then write a partial specialization that takes 2 template parameters `A` and `B`, and 1 type parameter `T`. If the types used in the declaration of the variable match the pattern `A<T>` and `B<T>` this specialization will be chosen:

```
template <template <typename> typename A,
          template <typename> typename B,
          typename T>
struct CommonTemplateTypeParameterProducer<A<T>, B<T>> 
{
  T Produce() { return T(); }
};
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MbKKf6Krc).